# Is there a more succint way to express this if expression in scala

Tags: scala

I'm just exploring scala.
Is there a more succint and/or more idiomatic way to write the following code?

```
def getValToAdd(c: Char): Int = {
  if ('(' == c) {
    1
  } else if (')' == c) {
    -1
  } else {
    0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove all of your curly brackets, they're redundant:

```
def getValToAdd(c: Char): Int =
  if ('(' == c) 1
  else if (')' == c) -1
  else 0
```

But a much more idiomatic way is to use [Pattern Matching](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/120)

```
def getValToAdd(c: Char): Int = c match {
  case '(' => 1
  case ')' => -1
  case _ => 0  
}
```

You can also drop the return type, the compiler can work it out:

```
def getValToAdd(c: Char) = c match {
  case '(' => 1
  case ')' => -1
  case _ => 0  
}
```

But I wouldn't recommend that unless this is a private utility method.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getValToAdd(c: Char): Int = c match {
    case '(' => 1
    case ')' => -1
    case _ => 0
}
```